# Dificuldade para Montar Consulta SQL com UNION com SUM

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, query

Tenho 2 tabelas que armazena tipo de vendas diferentes, e preciso somar tudo para chegar no valor para gerar o cobrança, porem não estou conseguindo montar a consulta sql, segue:

```
SELECT CL.NOME,CL.id_cadastro_cliente,  sum (L.VALOR_LANCAMENTO) as valor_total

 from (

(SELECT CL.NOME,CL.id_cadastro_cliente,  sum (L.VALOR_LANCAMENTO) as valor_total
 FROM CADASTRO_ATENDIMENTO AS C
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_ATENDIMENTO_ITEM AS L ON (C.id_cadastro_atendimento = L.id_cadastro_atendimento)
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente AS CL ON (CL.id_cadastro_cliente = C.id_cadastro_cliente)
 Where C.TIPO_OPERACAO = 'A VISTA' AND L.FATURA_NUMERO = 0 AND L.FATURA_ANO = 0 AND L.FATURA_PAGA = 'FALSE' AND C.REMETENTE LIKE '%'
 AND C.DATA_ATENDIMENTO BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
 group by CL.id_cadastro_cliente
 HAVING SUM(L.VALOR_LANCAMENTO) > 100
 ORDER BY CL.NOME)

union all

(SELECT CL.nOME, CL.id_cadastro_cliente, sum (contador_final - contador_inicial) as valor_total
 FROM cadastro_maquina_franquia_atendimento AS M
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente AS CL ON (CL.id_cadastro_cliente = M.id_cliente)
 WHERE CARTAO IS NULL AND ID_CLIENTE > 0
 group by CL.id_cadastro_cliente)


) as CONSULTA


INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente AS CL 
group by CL.id_cadastro_cliente
```

estou tendo o seguinte erro:

ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "group"
LINE 30: group by CL.id_cadastro_cliente

Comment: Você poderia colocar a estrutura das tabelas e formatar o sql como código, para facilitar o entendimento de quem deseja ajudar a resolver seu problema..

Comment: lhe peço desculpas, como seria uma formatação para facilitar o entendimento? pois assim pra mim está compreensível.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT CONSULTA.NOME,CONSULTA.ID_CLIENTE,  sum (CONSULTA.valor_total) as valor_total

from (

(SELECT CL1.NOME AS NOME,CL1.id_cadastro_cliente AS ID_CLIENTE,  sum (L1.VALOR_LANCAMENTO) as VALOR_TOTAL
 FROM CADASTRO_ATENDIMENTO AS C1
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_ATENDIMENTO_ITEM AS L1 ON (C1.id_cadastro_atendimento = L1.id_cadastro_atendimento)
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente AS CL1 ON (CL1.id_cadastro_cliente = C1.id_cadastro_cliente)
 Where C1.TIPO_OPERACAO = 'A VISTA' AND L1.FATURA_NUMERO = 0 AND L1.FATURA_ANO = 0 AND L1.FATURA_PAGA = 'FALSE' AND C1.REMETENTE LIKE '%'
 AND C1.DATA_ATENDIMENTO BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
 group by CL1.id_cadastro_cliente
 ORDER BY CL1.NOME)

union all

(SELECT CL2.nOME AS NOME, CL2.id_cadastro_cliente AS ID_CLIENTE, sum (contador_final - contador_inicial) as VALOR_TOTAL
 FROM cadastro_maquina_franquia_atendimento AS M2
 INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente AS CL2 ON (CL2.id_cadastro_cliente = M2.id_cliente)
 WHERE M2.CARTAO IS NULL AND M2.ID_CLIENTE > 0
 group by CL2.id_cadastro_cliente)

) as CONSULTA
group by CONSULTA.ID_CLIENTE, CONSULTA.NOME
HAVING SUM(CONSULTA.valor_total) > 200
ORDER BY CONSULTA.ID_CLIENTE

o erro na verdade era que no final deveria ser consulta.campo

Answer (score 1):

Falta colocar o ON do INNER JOIN antes do group by

```
INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente as CL ON CL.chave = ?.chave
```

Além disso... cada vez que voce utilizar uma tabela dentro do comando, voce deve nomeá-la de uma forma diferente...

No primeiro select voce faz `INNER JOIN` com `CADASTRO_Cliente as CL`.. no final voce faz outro `INNER JOIN CADASTRO_Cliente as CL`... deveria ser `CL2` por exemplo...